# Android: get active app names in active session

Tags: android, android-service, android-activitymanager

I've tried to get all names of applications which the user opened in a session (session start with unlocking phone and ends with turning off the screen).

As first I've tried to get the current app in the foreground. I use a service in the background and tried different code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

TaskListenerService.java:

```
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) TaskListenerService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
    String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo .topActivity.getPackageName();
    Toast.makeText(this, "name foregroundTaskInfo: " + foregroundTaskPackageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    PackageManager pm = TaskListenerService.this.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = null;
    try {
        foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
        String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "name foregroundTaskAppName: " + foregroundTaskAppName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It works fine in my own app, but if another app is in the foreground I get as package just "com.sec.android.app.launcher" ("TouchWiz-Start" as foregroundTaskAppName).
I also tried this code in TaskListenerService.java with the same result:

```
   ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo task:taskInfo) {
        if (task.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
            Toast.makeText(this, "name: " + task.processName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And this code...

```
   ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    componentInfo.getPackageName(); 
    Toast.makeText(this, "packageName: " + componentInfo.getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My Questions:

1. Is there another way to resolve my problem? Maybe with another
   approach to get all apps in a session?
2. Is there another solution without using GET_TASKS? (deprecated)